# Radio - click action and length action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have radios button on the page, when the page load, it will use length action to check and then hide/show some elements.

When user click on the radio, it will then hide and show some elements.

I'm wondering is this correct way doing it? Or how can it be improved?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(".delivery_type:radio").length > 0) {
    if ($('#methodPickup').is(':checked')) {
        $(".methodDelivery").hide();
        $("#addressBookSelectBlock").hide();
        $(".customAddress").hide();
    }
    if ($('#methodDelivery').is(':checked')) {
        $(".methodPickup").hide();
    }
}


$(".delivery_type:radio").live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "pickup") {
        $(".methodDelivery").hide();
        $(".methodPickup").show();
        $("#addressBookSelectBlock").hide();
        $(".customAddress").hide();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "delivery") {
        if ($(".selectAddressList").length == 0) {
            $(".customAddress").show();
        }

        $(".methodDelivery").show();
        $(".methodPickup").hide();
        $("#addressBookSelectBlock").show();
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine all the `hide()` and `show()` functions together:

```
if ($('#methodPickup').is(':checked')) {
  $(".methodDelivery, #addressBookSelectBlock, .customAddress").hide();
}
// etc...
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are using `live()` unless the radio buttons are being dynamically added or removed; just use `click()` if they are not dynamic.

Sharing some HTML and a little more information might help with more suggestions.